# VIMEO Api GET request in React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, vimeo

I am trying to get basic information from Vimeo API about searched video by it's ID
I have Token Client Identifier and Secrets but Api documentation is pretty complicated

The question is how to make a simple call to fetch data?

I already tried with axios:

```
const GetByIdVimeo = async (ID) => {
 const Token = 'MY_TOKEN'
   

const response = await axios.get({
    url: `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/${ID}`,
    Authorization: `bearer ${Token}`
}
)

const mofifiedResponse = {
    resp: response
}

return mofifiedResponse
}

export default GetByIdVimeo
```

But response is 404 not Found status rejected

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

The following code works.
First argument of axios.get() method is the url and the second a configuration object where you can specify your headers property. There you should place your authorization token.

```js
const GetByIdVimeo = async (ID) => {
  const Token = "YOUR_TOKEN";

  const response = await axios.get(`https://api.vimeo.com/videos/${ID}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Token}`,
    },
  });

  const mofifiedResponse = {
    resp: response,
  };

  return mofifiedResponse;
};

export default GetByIdVimeo
```

Keep in mind that you have to generate an unauthenticated access token to access data this way. Otherwise you have to use OAuth to authenticate, which may be more complicated.

[image]

Comment: To the point. It works. Thank you so much!